# Problem accessing the trash

Tags: opensuse, mate-desktop, gvfs

When trying to open the trash bin in mate , it pop up a window:  [image]
This means

```
Error: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Please select another viewer and try again
```

the trash bin can't be opened and it does not mount the flash and other storage devices.

When dolphin its launched (the kde file manager) the trash bin can be accessed/opened and the devices are listed and mounted like it normally does.

This seems to be gvfsd, so I just updated all the rpms related to it, but the issue persists.